# Prevent status bar from showing when Collapsing Toolbar Layout is collapsed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in my layout, in which I display an image. I tried to display the image till the top of the page, and that required to remove the status bar appearance. It works correctly when the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is expanded, like so :

[image: Status bar when collapsingToolbarLayout expanded]

But when I scroll down and the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` collapses, then the status bar suddenly appears :

[image: Status bar when collapsingToolbarLayout collapsed]

My layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="show"
            type="fr.steph.showmemories.models.ShowModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@id/details_toolbar">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/details_show_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:context="@{context}"
                    app:error="@{@drawable/ic_default_image}"
                    app:imageUrl="@{show.imageUrl}"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/details_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:title="@{show.name}"/>


            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/details_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            
            <!-- Page content -->

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

I looked for an answer but couldn't find anything related to this issue. How can I make the status bar stay invisible even when the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is collapsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution! The `statusBarScrim` attribute of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`changes the color of the status bar in collapsed state.

So setting it to `app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"` renders it invisible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:toolbarId="@id/details_toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/details_show_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/details_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the status bar from showing when the Collapsing Toolbar Layout is collapsed, you can use the **fitsSystemWindows** attribute and set it to **true** on the CollapsingToolbarLayout element. This will cause the Collapsing Toolbar Layout to "fit" the system windows, including the status bar, and the status bar will be hidden when the Collapsing Toolbar Layout is collapsed.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Your toolbar and other content goes here -->

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't work, it still behaves the same...except if I remove the `fitsSystemWindows` for the AppBarLayout, but then the status bar is visible when the CollapsingToolbarLayout is expanded.